# Extract all .bz2 in subfolders to another folder?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder hierarchy like below:

```
folder
-- subfolder1
---- file1.bz2
---- file2.bz2
---- file3.bz2
---- ...
-- subfolder2
---- file4.bz2
---- ...
-- subfolder3
---- file5.bz2
---- ...
-- ...
```

Inside each `.bz2` is a `.ppm` file. I want to extract all of the `.bz2` within `folder` to another folder, say `newFolder`.

```
// assume file.ppm is extracted from file.bz2
newFolder
-- file1.ppm
-- file2.ppm
-- file3.ppm
-- file4.ppm
-- file5.ppm
-- ...
```

Alternatively just `1.ppm`, `2.ppm`, etc. How can this be done in bash in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` and `-exec`, but you will need a helper script to handle the parameter expansions required to remove the `.bz2` extension from the original filename and add the `.ppm` extension.

You will change to the `newfolder` directory, and then the general form of the find command you will want is:

```
$ find /path/to/folder -type f -name "*bz2" -exec /path/to/helper.sh '{}' \;
```

Your helper script will decompress the bzip file preserving the original and redirecting the decompressed output to the new file in the current directory. (you should also do minimal validation that an argument was passed to `helper.sh` before blindly attempting to decompress). The helper script could be a simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && return 1   ## validate argument past
[ -r "$1" ] || return 1   ## validate argument is readable file

fn="${1##*/}"             ## remove path components

## decompress to stdout, preserving original, redirect to new name
bzip2 -cdk "$1" > "${fn%.bz2}.ppm"
```

(make sure you make `helper.sh` executable, e.g. `chmod +x /path/to/helper.sh`)

A short example beginning with a folder containing:

```
$ l1 ../folder
file1.bz2
file2.bz2
file3.bz2
file4.bz2
```

and the present directory `newfolder` empty with `helper.sh` in the parent directory, you would:

```
$ find ../folder -type f -name "*bz2" -exec ../helper.sh '{}' \;
```

Now the present directory `newfolder` contains the decompressed contents of the original `.bz2` files:

```
$ l1
file1.ppm
file2.ppm
file3.ppm
file4.ppm
```

with the original `.bz2` files preserved in the original directory `folder`.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: The argument to `-exec` can be `bash -c 'contents of helper.sh'` but if the helper script is complex and/or likely to be reused in other scenarios, keeping it in a separate file may still be warranted.

Comment: Yes, this one isn't too bad, so `bash -c '...'` would be fine. I just find it a bit more readable to use a helper for explanation purposes (including comments, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing lends itself to **GNU Parallel** which will:

- firstly, do all the jobs in parallel thereby using all your lovely Intel CPU cores you paid so much for, and
- secondly, easily strip paths, filenames and extensions from its parameters, or generate a *"sequence number"* which is what I actually chose to use,
- allow you to do a *"dry run"* to check things look good but without actually doing anything,
- allow a very succinct command without loops.

So, you can do:

```
mkdir -p results
find . -name \*.bz2 -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run 'bzip2 -cdk {} > results/{#}.ppm'
```

**Sample Output**

```
bzip2 -cdk ./folder/folder3/x.bz2 > results/3.ppm
bzip2 -cdk ./folder/folder2/x.bz2 > results/2.ppm
bzip2 -cdk ./folder/folder1/x.bz2 > results/1.ppm
bzip2 -cdk ./folder/folder4/x.bz2 > results/4.ppm
```

If that looks correct, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again to actually unzip the files.

Note that:

- `{}` means *"the current file"*
- `{#}` means *"the current job number within GNU Parallel"*

Other variables I alluded to but did not use:

- `{.}` means *"the current file minus the extension"*
- `{/}` means *"basename of current file"*
- `{//}` means *"dirname of current file"* ...

---

Note that you might like to use `parallel -k ...` when starting out because it **keeps** the output in order which is somewhat reassuring and avoids confusion.