# Run external application on multiple processors

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, subprocess, popen

Currently I have a program that uses `subprocess.Popen` to open an executable file and pass an argument - equivalent to running `./path/to/file args` on Linux.

This works very well but I have to execute this file over 1000 times and currently it is done one at a time, on a single processor. I want to be able to execute this file in sets of 8 for example, as I have an 8-core PC.

I have tried the following:

```
bolsig = ("/home/rdoyle/TEST_PROC/BOLSIG/bolsigminus")

infile_list = glob.glob(str(cwd)+"/BOLSIG Run Files/run*")

cmds_list = [[bolsig, infile] for infile in infile_list]
procs_list = [Popen(cmd) for cmd in cmds_list]           

for proc in procs_list:        
    proc.wait()
```

But this tries to execute all 1000 commands at the same time.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try **GNU Parallel**, example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319737/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like `concurrent.futures` for simple cases like this, it's so simple and yet so effective.

```
import os
import glob
from concurrent import futures
from subprocess import Popen

optim = ("/usr/bin/jpegoptim")
img_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir), 'images')

file_list = glob.glob(img_path+'/*jpg')

def compress(fname):
    Popen([optim, fname, '-d', 'out/', '-f'])

ex = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
ex.map(compress, file_list)
```

A great intro at Doug Hellman's PyMOTW. https://pymotw.com/3/concurrent.futures/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python `multiprocessing` module and its `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing